# Error while Loading stack of dictionaries to DataFrame in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading excel files in folder by filtering some files and looping though the files to get data. When I read excel, I am getting stack of dictionaries and I am trying to convert the dictionary to DataFrame but I am getting error. Below is my code

How can I get dictionaries to DataFrame?

```
p = Path(path to excel files)
filtered_files = [x for x in p.glob("**/*.xlsx") if not x.name.__contains__("AC0") and 
not x.name.startswith(".")
for i, file in enumerate(filtered_files):
# read file into a DataFrameF
df_xl = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=[0], header=0)
df = pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in df_xl.items()}).reset_index()
```

output of df_xl:

```
{0:        A  ... Unnamed: 4
 0    A01  ...        NaN
 1    A02  ...        NaN
 2    A03  ...        NaN
 3    A04  ...        NaN
 4   A04a  ...        NaN
  ..   ...  ...        ...
 92   NaN  ...        NaN
 93   NaN  ...        NaN
 94   NaN  ...        NaN
 95   NaN  ...        NaN
 96   NaN  ...        NaN

 [97 rows x 5 columns]}
 {0:        A  ... Unnamed: 4
  0    A01  ...        NaN
  1    A02  ...        NaN
  2    A03  ...        NaN
  3    A04  ...        NaN
  4   A04a  ...        NaN
   ..   ...  ...        ...
  92   NaN  ...        NaN
  93   NaN  ...        NaN
  94   NaN  ...        NaN
  95   NaN  ...        NaN
  96   NaN  ...        NaN

  [97 rows x 5 columns]}
```

Error:

The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or
a.all().

Comment: I used to stick with this error because I always used `and` and `or` in my logic statements. Try using `&` and `|` instead, respectively.

Comment: It's failing at statement   df = pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in df_xl.items()}).reset_index() and I did not use and/or in that statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say for sure without seeing your excel file(s), but it looks like df_xl is a dict that has DataFrames as values keyed by integers? Can you at least add the output of `type(df_xl)` to your question?

Assuming this is the case, it is still not clear from your output if the dataframes are all the same size, but if they are this should work

```
df = pd.concat(df_xl.values(), axis=1).reset_index()
```

or

```
df = pd.concat(df_xl.values(), ignore_index = True, axis=0).reset_index()
```